# error: no match for ‘operator=’

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the source in this repository:

https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr

And the compilation errors on this particular source file:

https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr/blob/master/src/GUI/PageOutput.cpp

with the following error:

```
../../src/GUI/PageOutput.cpp:66: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘((PageOutput*)this)->PageOutput::m_containers = {{"Matroska (MKV)", "matroska", {"mkv"}, "Matroska files (*.mkv)", {(PageOutput::enum_video_codec)0u, (PageOutput::enum_video_codec)1u, (PageOutput::enum_video_codec)2u}, {(PageOutput::enum_audio_codec)0u, (PageOutput::enum_audio_codec)1u, (PageOutput::enum_audio_codec)2u, (PageOutput::enum_audio_codec)3u}}, {"MP4", "mp4", {"mp4"}, "MP4 files (*.mp4)", {(PageOutput::enum_video_codec)0u}, {(PageOutput::enum_audio_codec)0u, (PageOutput::enum_audio_codec)1u, (PageOutput::enum_audio_codec)2u}}, {"WebM", "webm", {"webm"}, "WebM files (*.webm)", {(PageOutput::enum_video_codec)1u}, {(PageOutput::enum_audio_codec)0u}}, {"OGG", "ogg", {"ogg"}, "OGG files (*.ogg)", {(PageOutput::enum_video_codec)2u}, {(PageOutput::enum_audio_codec)0u}}, {"Other...", "", <brace-enclosed initializer list>(), "", <brace-enclosed initializer list>(), <brace-enclosed initializer list>()}}’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/vector.tcc:156: note: candidates are: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = PageOutput::ContainerData, _Alloc = std::allocator<PageOutput::ContainerData>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:336: note:                 std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&&) [with _Tp = PageOutput::ContainerData, _Alloc = std::allocator<PageOutput::ContainerData>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:356: note:                 std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(std::initializer_list<_Tp>) [with _Tp = PageOutput::ContainerData, _Alloc = std::allocator<PageOutput::ContainerData>]
make[2]: *** [simplescreenrecorder-PageOutput.o] Error 1
```

The offending code, properly formatted:

```
m_containers = {
        {"Matroska (MKV)", "matroska", {"mkv"}, "Matroska files (*.mkv)",
                {VIDEO_CODEC_H264, VIDEO_CODEC_VP8, VIDEO_CODEC_THEORA},
                {AUDIO_CODEC_VORBIS, AUDIO_CODEC_MP3, AUDIO_CODEC_AAC, AUDIO_CODEC_UNCOMPRESSED}},
        {"MP4", "mp4", {"mp4"}, "MP4 files (*.mp4)"     ,
                {VIDEO_CODEC_H264},
                {AUDIO_CODEC_VORBIS, AUDIO_CODEC_MP3, AUDIO_CODEC_AAC}},
        {"WebM", "webm", {"webm"}, "WebM files (*.webm)"   ,
                {VIDEO_CODEC_VP8},
                {AUDIO_CODEC_VORBIS,}},
        {"OGG", "ogg", {"ogg"}, "OGG files (*.ogg)"     ,
                {VIDEO_CODEC_THEORA},
                {AUDIO_CODEC_VORBIS}},
        {"Other...", "", {}, "", {}, {}},
};
```

I'm more of a C programmer and my C++ is a bit rusty. I have searched around and the error is common but have yet been unable to exactly figure out the problem with this one.

Comment: I don't think GCC 4.4.6 supports initializer list overloads.

Comment: I would rather prefer not to upgrade gcc if possible, is there a work around?

Comment: Not without changing that source file.

Comment: How would I change it? If it's not a trivial change I probably better upgrade gcc. Already had to work around a few other quirks due to gcc being an older version.

Comment: Make an array to hold those (assuming that's all aggregate initialization or something) and use `assign` with iterators to the beginning and end of the array.

Comment: Honestly, I would just upgrade gcc now. Chances are you're going to run into this kind of initialization more and more.

Comment: I agree. Typically if you run into an error with one source file, it will occur in many places. I've had my fair share of having to manually correct things in github projects to get them to compile.

Comment: All right I will upgrade, thanks for the feedback. Chris if you want write your comment as an answer so I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC 4.4.6 doesn't support having a `std::initializer_list` as a parameter, so list assignment isn't possible. However, it's fairly easy to work around if upgrading GCC is not possible:

```
PageOutput::ContainerData temp[] = {
        {"Matroska (MKV)", "matroska", {"mkv"}, "Matroska files (*.mkv)",
                {VIDEO_CODEC_H264, VIDEO_CODEC_VP8, VIDEO_CODEC_THEORA},
                {AUDIO_CODEC_VORBIS, AUDIO_CODEC_MP3, AUDIO_CODEC_AAC, AUDIO_CODEC_UNCOMPRESSED}},
        {"MP4", "mp4", {"mp4"}, "MP4 files (*.mp4)"     ,
                {VIDEO_CODEC_H264},
                {AUDIO_CODEC_VORBIS, AUDIO_CODEC_MP3, AUDIO_CODEC_AAC}},
        {"WebM", "webm", {"webm"}, "WebM files (*.webm)"   ,
                {VIDEO_CODEC_VP8},
                {AUDIO_CODEC_VORBIS,}},
        {"OGG", "ogg", {"ogg"}, "OGG files (*.ogg)"     ,
                {VIDEO_CODEC_THEORA},
                {AUDIO_CODEC_VORBIS}},
        {"Other...", "", {}, "", {}, {}},
};

m_containers.assign(std::begin(temp), std::end(temp));
```

I can't remember if `std::begin/end` exist in that version, but they're trivial to implement otherwise:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
T *begin(const T(&arr)[N]) {return arr;}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
T *end(const T(&arr)[N]) {return arr + N;}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you :-) The code fix is also very helpful to get an insight.